# New to MVC cannot get data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

I'm completely new to MVC.  I following a tutorial where you are supposed to connect to a database and pull data from a table.  Unfortunately This is not working. I'm supposed to be able to add "/Employee/Details/1" to the address bar after "localhost:12345" and get the values located in the first row of the table.   I'm not sure what code to post so I will post what I think is relevant and a copy of the error details.  Please let me know if I need to post more code in order to get more help.  Thanks!

EmployeeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcDemo2.Models;

namespace MvcDemo2.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Employee/

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);  //THIS IS THE LINE HIGHLIGHTED AS PART OF THE ERROR
            return View(employee);
        }

    }
}
```

<-------next file-------->

```
Employee.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcDemo2.Models
{

     [Table("dbo.Employees")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }



    }
}
```

<-------next file-------->

EmployeeContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;


namespace MvcDemo2.Models
{


    public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

<-------next file-------->

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext"
         connectionString="server=MISSIONCNTRL-PC\SQLEXPRESS; database=Sample; integrated security=SSPI"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

<-------next file-------->

Global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcDemo2
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode,
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MvcDemo2.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

<-----Error Message----->

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Sequence contains no elements
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.Single[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
       at MvcDemo2.Controllers.EmployeeController.Details(Int32 id) in d:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcDemo2\MvcDemo2\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs:line 18
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

FYI. I have read through the other threads that are using the same tutorial and have tried their code but I still have no luck.  Could really use some help on this one. It important to me to try to figure this out.

Comment: Could someone at least tell me what the error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
    Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Find(id);
    if (employee != null) 
      return View(employee);

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

Comment: Well that seems to have moved me farther in the code, but now I get a new error.  This is in a view file I had not posted.  I'll post it and the error below (since I cant seem to figure out how to post it in this box)

Comment: Posted view file and error  in above answer.  Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: You are getting that error because employee was not found so employee you are passing will be null. Check my updated answer above so when employee is null it will return 404 error. Check this on how to handle [404 error](http://setiabud.blogspot.com/2013/04/handling-404-error-in-aspnet-mvc.html).

Comment: Pated it in and getting compile error "The name 'HttpStatusCode' does not exist in the current context." I added "using System.Net" to the file but still gives error. Please advise...

Comment: change it to this HttpStatusCodeResult(404);

Comment: Got the 404.  I'll try to use the code in the link you gave me and see if that helps.  If/when I have issues I'll continue to post here.  Again, Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you are getting 404 then employee doesn't exist in database so add new employee in database then it should work.

Comment: Quick question: Is employee coming up null because it cant find it in the DB?

Comment: Yes, so check Employee table with ID you are trying to find.

Comment: Ahh yes! Thats the problem. I thought that the  controller was supposed to pull the data from the first row, dispite the actuall id.  I wa wron.  Looking back at the table in the tutorial the EmployeeId's are 1,2,3,4.  I had changed them in my code because I thought that they were irrelevent. I guess I should have paid more attention to the video!  Thanks for your help!  I can finally move on with the tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

```
@model MvcDemo2.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Employee Details</h2>
<table style="font-family: Arial">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Employee Id:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.EmployeeId //this is where the error is 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Name:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.Name
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Gender:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.Gender
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>City:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.City
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

<--------ERROR Message-------->

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=App_Web_qs2w0l3a
  StackTrace:
       at ASP._Page_Views_Employee_Details_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcDemo2\MvcDemo2\Views\Employee\Details.cshtml:line 14
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

Thankyou dasu908 for the help.  I'm really getting frustraited with this.